# How to improve the speed of this for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop

```
for i in range(0, num):
    for j in range(0, 10000):
        one_arr[int(j/100), j%100, :] = all_data[i].iloc[j,2:16]
```

Basically, this part of my code is just running too slowly. I think that the for-loop is the cause of the slow runtime. Is there any faster way to accomplish the same task?

*all_data* is a list whose element is a pandas data frame.

Comment: Is there any way you can avoid nesting the for-loops?Nesting the loops automatically converts the runtime of this code to O(n^2). Is `num` a large number?

Comment: Which version of python?

Comment: RHS of the assignment is an array hence can be assigned directly if you compute the LHS indices. `one_arr[<x indices>, <y indices>] = all_data[i].iloc[:, 2:16]` But I think you have an error since this would overwrite the same array.

Comment: You overwrite the same piece of `one_arr` every time (the slice depends on `j` but not `i`).  So you can simply remove the outer loop and set `i = num - 1`, then run the inner loop once.  This will give a huge speedup if `num` is large.

Comment: num is not  a large number, its like 500

Comment: Sorry, I should make it clearer, I will assign the `one_arr` later, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

Try to Use [Pypy](http://pypy.org) it will translate your code into Machine Language so it can run faster. it takes time to create your Script but it runs fast and Compatible with any machine